# To commit locally in Intellij, do you install git.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am completely new to Java, Intellij and Eclipse.

Recently, I was assigned to

1. Set up local Git repository.
2. Commit to Git repository locally.
3. Set up a remote Git repository on Github and push it.

In Eclipse, I do the following easily

1. Set up a Gradle project.
2. Modify a Library.java file under the directory of src/main/java.
3. Open Gradle Task and Gradle application thru "show view"
4. Press run under "application".
5. Configure Git repository.

So after some Googling, it seems that to start a local repository in Intellij, I have to create Git repository under the "VCS" tab.

However, Intellij said I need git.exe.

So my question is, do I need to download git.exe?

If yes, why doesn't eclipse's gradle project require git.exe?

And, to create a local repository and share it to Github, do I need a gradle project in Intellij?

Comment: what is this git.exe? You need git version control installed on your system in order to access git commands and remote repositories. I believe you knew that.

Comment: Intellij responded to my "create git repository" by saying "File not found: git.exe". I really don't know I need git version control since I don't need it in Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse uses [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), a Git implementation in Java, whereas Intellij delegates to [git-core](https://git-scm.com/), the command line Git.

Comment: Why Eclipse, in particular, require me to run Gradle task before creating local repository?

Comment: @AndesLam Eclipse, Gradle and Git aren't related (one's an IDE, one's a build tool and one's a VCS), so it can't be a *requirement*. Just because you did it that way doesn't mean it's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VCS tab on Intellij means "Version Control System" which gives you options to interact with a VCS tool such as Github, which acts as the repository for your code base. In the "terminal" view on Intellij, you can then use your standard Github commands, so you could use git clone (url from Github) -b (branchname) to pull down your code for the first time. And yes you will need to download git.exe but refer to documentation for full steps.

Intellij and Eclipse are both IDE's, so having used both I would recommend using Intellij but everyone has their own personal preference.

For future usage, here's the basic commands to push to GH as you require:

```
git status (to check the files you've changed)
git add * (to add all files amended) or git add (filepath)
git commit -m "Message to commit"
git push origin (branchname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipes uses JGit, enbaded git, so you can run it without installing a git.
However Intellij haven't a build in git then you have to install it and give Intellij the path for it. (That's why he asked for the path to git.exe).
Go to https://git-scm.com/ and download it.

for github, you just need to config the remotes.
if you got already git ( you already did `git init`)
then just

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/*user*/*project-name*.git
```

and then push.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.

Git is a version control system for tracking changes in computer files and coordinating work on those files among multiple people.

Read more in [what is git?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)

When you understand it, it is obvious that you need to install git locally on the computer.

### IntelliJ

Intellij has a plugin helps you working with git.

If you read carefully [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html), you'll see that you need to download and install git before using the IntelliJ plugin.

### Eclipse

Eclipse on the other hand uses [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), a pure java library implementing git version control system.

The Eclipse Git plugin that is called [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/), is using JGit. Which means that you do not actually need to install git in this case.

Since you are completely new with Java, IntelliJ and Eclipse let my give you a good rule of thumb.

If you are working with java and git it is recommended that they will be installed in your computer properly.

IntelliJ and Eclipse are just IDEs with them you can work on your project.

In a properly configured project, you can work either with IntelliJ or Eclipse. It doesn't really matter.

You should not be dependent on any of these IDEs.